# Hint for $(1+e^y)\cos(t)dt + e^y\sin(y)dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have tried to find hints using Mathematica but it did not worked. I can not able to convert problem into any form Which I know how to solve this DE. Can you give me a hint?
$$(1+e^y)\cos (t)dt + e^y\sin (y)dy = 0$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is separable: It can be rearranged to yield

$$\cos t dt = -\frac{e^y \sin y}{1 + e^y} dy$$

Integrating the right side is possible, but [not so very nice.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20e%5Ey%20sin%28y%29%20/%20%281%20%2b%20e%5Ey%29)

Comment: Yes, I did that but i was not able to take integral of right hand side. Mathematica did not give a simple result for integral of right hand side too. It was too long and complicated.

Comment: Can you think an other,  much simpler than integral of rhs, way?

Comment: @OlcayErtaş I'd start by writing $\sin$ as a complex exponential or using $\sinh$ and $\cosh$. I don't see a way to get rid of the [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.